# Unix File extension validation Fails

Tags: shell, unix

Something I am missing that I am not able to figure out.. Need some thoughts..

I am trying to check file extensions in a directory only file extensions I get .txt or .TXT ) .. but both should be treated as different as I am performing different validations for .txt and .TXT files..

I have  the below files

```
aa.394.63.txt
aa.394.23.TXT
```

Here is my code

```
for file in "$SEARCH_DIR"/*; do
  extn=$(echo $file | awk -F '.' '{print $NF}')
  echo "extn:" $extn
  if [ $extn=="txt" ]; then
     echo "txt Loop"
  elif [$extn=="TXT" ]; then
     echo "TXT loop"
  fi
```

But this script always be true for the "txt" validations never goes to the "TXT loop".. I think unix is case sensitive and it should be treated as separate.. Pls advise what am I missing ..

Comment: Try adding spaces: `if [ $extn == "txt" ]` and `elif [ $extn == "TXT" ]`.

Answer (score 2):

You're using `test` in the form of `[]` to test your conditions. You must include spaces around the brackets and the equality operators.

From the `test` man page:

> [ is a synonym for test but requires a final argument of ]
>   ...
>
> Spaces around the brackets are important - each operator and operand must be a separate argument.
>   https://ss64.com/bash/test.html

This means that you need to pay careful attention to spaces in your test constructs. You should also note that variables should be quoted when you're testing them with `[]`, as they may have undergone word splitting (not relevant in this case, but probably a good habit).

Because you're using `[]` to test conditons, rather than the bash `[[]]` construct, you should use a single `=` framed with whitespace as a test for string equality.

The following is a slightly amended version of your code and should work:

```
#!/bin/bash

SEARCH_DIR=./search
for file in "$SEARCH_DIR"/*; do
    extn=$(echo $file | awk -F '.' '{print $NF}')
    echo "extn:" "$extn"
    if [ "$extn" = "txt" ]; then
        echo "txt Loop"
    elif [ "$extn" =  "TXT" ]; then
        echo "TXT loop"
    fi
done
```

### References

- [test man page](https://ss64.com/bash/test.html)
- [Comparison operators in bash](https://www.tldp.org/LDP/abs/html/comparison-ops.html)

Comment: You beat me to it :)  BAD: `elif [$extn=="TXT" ]; then`  GOOD: `elif  [ "$extn" = "TXT" ]; then`.  And per the OP's other question: Yes, "==" and "=" are case sensitive.

Comment: Glad it helped @Anto